# Cannot connect to self-signed localhost server with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire

I'm creating an app that hooks in with a basic web service hosted on the same computer, but I've been unable to get past this SSL error. There's some existing questions about this on Stack Overflow, but I've been unable to get those solutions working as you can see in the code below:

```
let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "https://localhost:5001": .disableEvaluation
    ]

    return SessionManager(
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
}()

class DataGetter {

    open class MyServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {
        open override func serverTrustPolicy(forHost host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
            return ServerTrustPolicy.disableEvaluation
        }
    }

    let sessionManager = SessionManager(delegate:SessionDelegate(), serverTrustPolicyManager:MyServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: [:]))

    func getSessionData(sessionId: Int) -> SessionAttendance {

        let session = SessionAttendance()
        let requestUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/todo/" + String(sessionId)
        Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                print("JSON: \(json)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return session
    }
}
```

When I try to run the *getSessionData* method, I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “localhost” which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

I've tried enabling *NSAllowsLocalNetworking,NSAllowsArbitraryLoads*, and added "localhost" under Exception Domains inside my info.plist. I have also exported my .cer certificate from keychain and installed it onto the simulator. I've tried the workarounds given for Alamofire in other questions, as you can see in the code above. None of these solutions have worked.

Does anybody know how to fix this error so I can receive data from my local web service? Thanks.

Edit: Part of my info.plist file

```
key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: tried http instead of https ??

Comment: For the purposes of this project, I cannot use http unfortunately.

Comment: What is the CN and SANs in the certificate? If nowhere localhost, then you have a name mismatch. If you want to keep doing HTTPS properly even locally, follow advices here (on not using localhost name or using self signed certificate): https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/ . Also if you have a purely local to local traffic that is guaranteed to never exit the machine in the future, then TLS (HTTPS) makes no sense, you do not need its feature for a purely local connection (except if it become external later outside of your tests).

Comment: If this is an iOS app then using localhost makes no sense - localhost is the iOS device itself.  Using TLS without a valid certificate to authenticate the server doesn't really do anything to protect you, but if you must you should be able to just disable ATS.  Show the part of your info.plist where you allowed arbitrary loads.

Comment: Paul, I'm running the app on the iOS simulator, so the local IP should be the same. I've edited the relevant portion of my plist file into the question post.